# Aligning two elements with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two elements, a `<button>` and a `<ul>`. There are multiple of the button, and they all do the same thing. When you click a button, I want to move the ul to the button (aligned at the top right). The buttons don't have IDs.

The menu (UL) will be absolute positioned. They are not siblings/parents/children of each other. When you click the button, it calls a function. I hope this function can move the UL to the location of the button that you clicked.

HTML:

```
<button class="download" onclick="showDownloadMenu()"><i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>

<ul id="download-menu">
    <h1>Downloads</h1>
    <button id="download-close-button" onclick="hideDownloadMenu()"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
    <li><a href="/">option 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">option 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">option 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">option 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">option 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript:

**option 1** - this makes sense in my head... the right side of the menu equals the right side of the button..

```
downloadMenu.right = (clickedButton.right)+'px';
```

kind of works on buttons on the left...

[image]

but the buttons on the right go even further left, something is definitely wrong

[image]

**option 2** - closest to working but instead of the right side of the menu aligning with the right side of the button, the left side of the menu is. these at least are consistant, but it's not in the right place.

```
downloadMenu.left = (clickedButton.right)+'px';
```

[image]

**option 3** - not sure, but it was the last thing to try

```
downloadMenu.left = (clickedButton.left)+'px';
```

[image]

once again this is consistant, and even closer, but now the left side of the button and the left side of the menu are aligned.

so you'd think making it right/right would do the opposite, but as seen above thats not the case.

Comment: restucture your question, it is hard to understand what you need to achieve and where you are stuck.

Comment: agree with @A.J please rephrase your question and if possible add some code examples of what you have so far

Comment: it's better if you give a screenshot of what's currently happening as well as your expected result. Also put your html / javascript that you have done so far.

Comment: We will need to see your actual HTML and then maybe a screenshot of what you're trying to achieve.  If the UL is absolutely positioned, it can be moved relative to any other element in the page to wherever you want, but we'd need to see your actual HTML to advise.

Comment: I added my HTML and also a screenshot to give you a better idea. Theres those two download buttons, and I want the menu to jump to the one you click on. The menu (UL) will be absolute positioned.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. When the button is clicked, just change the coordinates (`top` etc.) of the `<ul>` to something based on the coordinates of the button. You can retrieve those with `getBoundingClientRect`.

Comment: I tried getBoundingClientRect, but and having some issues with it. I outlined it with pictures in my post above. thanks for the responses

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick fiddle, hope that is what you meant.

```js
    $('button').click(function(){
            $('ul').insertAfter($(this))
    })
```

```css
    button {display: block; margin-top: 20px;}
```

```html
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <button>one</button>
    <button>two</button>
    <button>three</button>
    <button>four</button>

    <ul>
            <li>xxx</li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Trying to avoid JQuery if I can, but thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Well, do the same without it :-)